# php mysql video upload not successfully functioning

Tags: php, mysql, video

**I am getting the following errors:**

> 1. Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access DENIED for user 'a5467268_andrew'@'10.1.1.19' (using password: YES) in /home/a5467268/public_html/andrew/fileupload.php on line 2
> 2. Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a VALID MySQL-Link resource in /home/a5467268/public_html/andrew/fileupload.php on line 3

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("","","");
mysql_select_db("login",$con);
extract($_POST);

$target_dir = "test_upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if($upd)
{
//$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$imageFileType= $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"];

if($imageFileType != "video/mp4" && $imageFileType != "video/avi" && $imageFileType != "video/mov" && $imageFileType != "video/3gp" && $imageFileType != "video/mpeg")
{
    echo "File Format Not Supported";
} 
else
{
$video_path=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
mysql_query("insert into video(video_name) values('$video_path')");
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],"test_upload/".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
echo "uploaded ";
}
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Choose Video<input type="file" name="fileToUpload"/>
<input type="submit" value="uplaod" name="upd"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Your database is either not online, either you provide wrong credentials.

Comment: NEVER show your credentials on a website!

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access DENIED for
>   user 'a5467268_andrew'@'10.1.1.19' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/a5467268/public_html/andrew/fileupload.php on line 2

This occurs when you're using a password for a db user that doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
mysql_connect('server_name','db_user','db_user_password');
```

Comment: Request Entity Too Large
The requested resource
/andrew/fileupload.php
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Comment: If you are working locally, you can edit php.ini to allow large file upoload. Check if post_max_size and upload_max_filesize values are greater than your file size.